# Signed JAR being blocked by Java Security

Tags: java, security, permission-denied, sign

I'm racking my brains as to why when I'm signing my JAR using a code signing certificate which has been used before, I still get a Java Security Application Blocked dialog which stipulates that my application is self-signed:

[image]

However, when I run the jarsigner verify command from a machine that I didn't use to sign the app (replaced actual company name with Acme for anonymity):

```
jarsigner -verify -certs -verbose RegistrySafeLauncher.jar


s        821 Wed Oct 21 09:25:42 BST 2015 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

      X.509, CN="Acme Software, Inc.", OU=Acme Software Corp, OU=Digital ID Class 3 - Java Object Signing, O="Acme Software, Inc.", L=Sunnyvale, ST=California, C=US
      [certificate is valid from 11/5/13 12:00 AM to 11/4/16 11:59 PM]
      X.509, CN=VeriSign Class 3 Code Signing 2010 CA, OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)10, OU=VeriSign Trust Network, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US
      [certificate is valid from 2/8/10 12:00 AM to 2/7/20 11:59 PM]
      X.509, CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5, OU="(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=VeriSign Trust Network, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US
      [certificate is valid from 11/8/06 12:00 AM to 11/7/21 11:59 PM]
      X.509, OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US
      [certificate is valid from 1/29/96 12:00 AM to 8/3/28 12:59 AM]

         561 Wed Oct 21 09:25:42 BST 2015 META-INF/MYKEY.SF
        5345 Wed Oct 21 09:25:42 BST 2015 META-INF/MYKEY.RSA
           0 Wed Oct 21 09:25:44 BST 2015 META-INF/
           0 Wed Oct 21 09:25:44 BST 2015 registrysafelauncher/
sm      1067 Wed Oct 21 09:25:42 BST 2015 META-INF/INDEX.LIST

      X.509, CN="Acme Software, Inc.", OU=Acme Software Corp, OU=Digital ID Class 3 - Java Object Signing, O="Acme Software, Inc.", L=Sunnyvale, ST=California, C=US
      [certificate is valid from 11/5/13 12:00 AM to 11/4/16 11:59 PM]
      X.509, CN=VeriSign Class 3 Code Signing 2010 CA, OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)10, OU=VeriSign Trust Network, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US
      [certificate is valid from 2/8/10 12:00 AM to 2/7/20 11:59 PM]
      X.509, CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5, OU="(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=VeriSign Trust Network, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US
      [certificate is valid from 11/8/06 12:00 AM to 11/7/21 11:59 PM]
      X.509, OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US
      [certificate is valid from 1/29/96 12:00 AM to 8/3/28 12:59 AM]

sm      1441 Wed Oct 21 09:25:44 BST 2015 registrysafelauncher/RegistrySafeLauncher$1.class

      X.509, CN="Acme Software, Inc.", OU=Acme Software Corp, OU=Digital ID Class 3 - Java Object Signing, O="Acme Software, Inc.", L=Sunnyvale, ST=California, C=US
      [certificate is valid from 11/5/13 12:00 AM to 11/4/16 11:59 PM]
      X.509, CN=VeriSign Class 3 Code Signing 2010 CA, OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)10, OU=VeriSign Trust Network, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US
      [certificate is valid from 2/8/10 12:00 AM to 2/7/20 11:59 PM]
      X.509, CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5, OU="(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=VeriSign Trust Network, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US
      [certificate is valid from 11/8/06 12:00 AM to 11/7/21 11:59 PM]
      X.509, OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US
      [certificate is valid from 1/29/96 12:00 AM to 8/3/28 12:59 AM]

sm      1765 Wed Oct 21 09:25:44 BST 2015 registrysafelauncher/RegistrySafeLauncher.class

      X.509, CN="Acme Software, Inc.", OU=Acme Software Corp, OU=Digital ID Class 3 - Java Object Signing, O="Acme Software, Inc.", L=Sunnyvale, ST=California, C=US
      [certificate is valid from 11/5/13 12:00 AM to 11/4/16 11:59 PM]
      X.509, CN=VeriSign Class 3 Code Signing 2010 CA, OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)10, OU=VeriSign Trust Network, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US
      [certificate is valid from 2/8/10 12:00 AM to 2/7/20 11:59 PM]
      X.509, CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5, OU="(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=VeriSign Trust Network, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US
      [certificate is valid from 11/8/06 12:00 AM to 11/7/21 11:59 PM]
      X.509, OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US
      [certificate is valid from 1/29/96 12:00 AM to 8/3/28 12:59 AM]


  s = signature was verified 
  m = entry is listed in manifest
  k = at least one certificate was found in keystore
  i = at least one certificate was found in identity scope

jar verified.

Warning: 
This jar contains signatures that does not include a timestamp. Without a timestamp, users may not be able to validate this jar after the signer certificate's expiration date (2016-11-04) or after any future revocation date.
```

And the manifest file in the built JAR looks like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.4
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase: *.acme.net http://localhost*
Application-Name: RegistrySafeLauncher
Class-Path: lib/jna-4.2.0.jar lib/jna-platform-4.2.0.jar
Permissions: all-permissions
Created-By: 1.7.0_80-b15 (Oracle Corporation)
Caller-Allowable-Codebase: *.acme.net http://localhost*
Main-Class: registrysafelauncher.RegistrySafeLauncher
Codebase: *

Name: registrysafelauncher/RegistrySafeLauncher.class
SHA-256-Digest: lA2UH1iNCFqmNeXTlD/5Gik+DGfkA64F34T3i6ArSEM=

Name: registrysafelauncher/RegistrySafeLauncher$1.class
SHA-256-Digest: kNyCx9f9FwWHAV/Mf4D+9KIJJfFHdcrTUNnEdiXwWmw=

Name: META-INF/INDEX.LIST
SHA-256-Digest: 7A/Nhqqvf7wBQNaAj0actnzwuWocUJv6R8/+QZyURmw=
```

What am I missing? Am I missing something in my manifest file or is the link to the CA (VeriSign) not right on the machine I'm building on?

****** Later update: ******

After playing around with my jnlp file so that it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<jnlp codebase="http://localhost/jnlptestcaller" href="launch.aspx" spec="1.0+">
    <information>
        <title>RegistrySafeLauncher</title>
        <vendor>Acme Software, Inc.</vendor>
        <homepage href=""/>
        <description>RegistrySafeLauncher</description>
        <description kind="short">RegistrySafeLauncher</description>
    </information>
    <update check="background"/>
    <security>
<all-permissions/>
</security>
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.7+"/>
        <jar href="RegistrySafeLauncher.jar" main="true"/>
        <jar href="lib/jna-4.2.0.jar"/>
        <jar href="lib/jna-platform-4.2.0.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <application-desc main-class="registrysafelauncher.RegistrySafeLauncher">
        <argument>JavaAgent.jnlp.aspx</argument>
    </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

I now get this slightly different security warning:

[image: Java Security Blocked]

How can I get rid of this warning?

Comment: It seems that no-one knows...

Comment: The only way I could solve this was to rollback my Java version from 1.7 update 80 to update 45. Not really what I wanted to do but it solved it for my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that my certificate was fine. Java doesn't behave well with localhost so I put a host file entry in to point localtest to localhost and it worked running it from localtest (could have also used my IP).

Answer (score 1):

[As of Java 7 update 51 self-signed certificates will be blocked](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/java_blocked.xml).

As the linked page discusses, there are numerous resources for "properly implementing secure practices":

> - [JAR File Manifest Attributes for Security](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/security/manifest.html)
> - [Java SE 7 Security Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/)
> - [Secure Coding Guidelines for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/seccodeguide-139067.html)

And while this is not a general solution (because you should not expect users to do this), for a quick fix:

> you can use the Exception Site list feature to run the applications blocked by security settings. [Adding the URL of the blocked application to the Exception Site list](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/exception_sitelist.xml) allows it to run with some warnings.

Comment: also, [as of Java 8 update 20 medium-level java security is also blocked](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/jcp_security.xml). This seems to be the case for OP, as the dialog he's getting tells that only high and very high levels are available.